# Ruby gives different results for different approaches to array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to append some values to a particular array in an array of arrays, like this:

```
a1 = [[]] * 2
a1[0] << -1
a1 # => [[-1], [-1]]
a2 = [[], []]
a2[0] << -1
a2 # => [[-1], []]
[[]] * 2 == [[], []] # => true
```

`a2` has the expected value while `a1` seems to be wrong. What I was expecting is `a1` to have the value `[[-1], []]` since I changed `a1[0]` & not `a1[1]`.

Comment: In the first case, the two elements are actually the same array. When you change one, the other sees the change.

Comment: How is it wrong? What is the issue? You tell us.

Comment: @sawa I have edited the answer to express what I expected. However, now I understand the issue as shivam has pointed out.

Comment: @kamalbanga in that case I was expecting my answer to be accepted :(

Comment: @shivam: When I tried to accept your answer, there was yet time to be able to do that. Later I forgot. I have accepted it now :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use:

```
a1 = Array.new(2) { [] }
```

`[[]]*2` is for repetition and is just repeating the same object `[]` twice.

To support of my above point:

```
a1 = [[]] * 2
a1.map(&:object_id)
#=> [26686760, 26686760]   # same object ids

a3 = Array.new(2) { [] }
a3.map(&:object_id)
#=> [23154760, 23154680]   # different object ids
```

Answer (score 2):

Both subarrays in your `a1` are the same `Array` object.